# What is 'success_url' variable default value

Tags: django

I am creating a form in Django by extending the CreateView class and everything works fine.

But what I don't quite understand is that when the form is submitted, web browser automatically redirects me to the url specified by model's get_absolute_url() method.

Is it a default behavior that 'success_url' field is at some point assigned by an url returned by that method?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The [default implementation of `get_success_url()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L143) on CreateView calls the models' `get_absolute_url` if no other value is defined.

Comment: Can you show your view code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's exactly the case. Looks like I didn't dig the documentation deep enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your view class defines a `success_url` attribute this is used as the success url. Otherwise it will use `get_absolute_url()` method of the created/edited object. See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).

So if you don't want to redirect to the object's absolute url you can either define `success_url` on the class or re-define the class' [`get_success_url()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L143) method if you need to fine-tune it more.